# Using the master theorem

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

Use the master theorem to put `O()` bounds on this statement:

`T(n) = 16T(n/4) + n2 + log n`

I'm trying to understand the master theorem more and more and trying to find more examples online and getting their solutions.

Comment: Dude, we're not doing your homework for you. I frankly think you already got too much done for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/597861/user597861

Comment: Do you know what builds confidence? Practice. It's the same as learning to ride a bike, or pick up chicks, or solving CS problems: practice, repeated failure, picking your ass back up, and trying again.

Comment: Give us your result we'll say if it is correct

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. It also doesn't describe a specific problem, but just asks to solve the task for OP.

Answer (score 2):

I think this [resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) is enough for this question

Answer (score 0):

T(n)=16T(n/4)+n^2+log n ==> T(n)=16T(n/4)+n^2. Because  n^lg16=n^2 the result is o(n^2 log n)